# Does multiple negotiation after refusing the offered salary can withdraw the offer

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, salary, job-offer, negotiation

I currently got an offer from a company , they proposed a salary of X amount but I am currently looking for 20 % of X amount.

So, I sent a mail to HR, regarding my expected salary but she replied that the job I applied for is restricted to  X amount of salary, they cannot propose more than X amount. I requested again in e-mail listing few reasons that why I need the hike.

On that basis, she again restricted or refused with some positive notes that if I stay for long term, then I will definitely achieve my expected salary.

But in the end of the mail she wrote :- **"Thanks again for your understanding and I shall get back to you soon."**

So, it's been more than 2 days, the HR  didn't replied me anything, so do I understand that my job offer is gone, as I negotiated with the company even after the HR mentioned multiple times that the salary is restricted.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the workplace! You are not actually asking anything, so why don't you rephrase your question, including what you want to achieve in this situation

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be more of an English language question than a workplace one (but no, "shall" conveys certainty, not doubt).

Comment: Well, it used to be an English language question, now it's more opinion-based - they're the only ones who know whether the offer has or will be withdrawn, or when they'll get back to you (if you're willing to accept the lower salary, you might want to just tell them that, within the next week or so, because "soon" could be anything from hours to months; if you don't want to accept it, just wait for a reply).

Comment: For future reference, your needs are not their concern. "... few reasons that why I need the hike" is not important to them, what you need to demonstrate is why your value is that high.

Answer (score 1):

> "Thanks again for your understanding and I shall get back to you
>   soon."

The word *soon* is vague, and the word *shall* in this context simply means "I will".

Perhaps **they were vague on purpose** because they did not know how long it would take to get an appropriate response.  Be patient with this person, and if you don't get a response in a week or so, I would reach back out for an update.

**Short answer**:  Reach out to them again for an update in a week or so.

Answer (score 1):

**Give it at least a week, maybe more.**

The company has a budget of X for the position.  They like you as a candidate, but you require 1.2X and you have made that clear to them.

The company now has to determine:

1. Are they willing to pay 1.2X for that position?
2. Do they have 1.2X / can they afford it?  Will they have to extract 0.2X from some other budget item?
3. If the answer to the first two questions is "yes", then they still need to decide if you are the person they will pay 1.2X to for the position.

**Determining all of that takes time**.

Don't give up on them, but at the same time you may as well continue interviewing for other positions (you never stop that until you actually have the job).

By the way, "shall" implies a clear intent to get back to you.  "soon" says the person does not know when this will happen, probably because it is not under his control.

Comment: The company also might have had another candidate who wanted 20% more and didn't get the job, even though they were the better candidate.